# Facing status code 400 while using React Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest, jest-fetch-mock

I am learning unit testing using Jest in React. I want to test status 200 and 400 when my api returns me to reponse. But First one is passing test but second one is facing **Request failed with status code 400 error** ant then Second case is failed with that. Why am I facing that ? I took a group my cases and I mocked my axios get method with axios-mock-adapter. What is problem do you think. What should I do ? Her is my example code.

UserService.test.ts :

```
import { ACCOUNT_SETTINGS } from '../../core/constants/apiEndpoints'
import mockServiceInstance from '../__mocks__/MockService'
import { fetchUsersMockData, userClaimsTreeMockData } from "../__mocks__/UserServiceMockData";
import axios from "axios";
import MockAdapter from "axios-mock-adapter";

afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks()
});

const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);

// roles/list?PageIndex=0&PageSize=3
describe('fetchAllUsers method', () => {
    let url : string = `${ACCOUNT_SETTINGS.PAGED_LIST}?PageIndex=${0}&PageSize=${3}`;
    
    it("get is succesfull", async () => {
        const mockData = {
            result: fetchUsersMockData,
            error: null,
            isSuccessful: true
        }

        mock.onGet(url).reply(200, mockData);
        const { data } = await axios.get(url)
        expect(data.result).toStrictEqual(fetchUsersMockData);

    })

    it("get has error", async () => {
        mock.onGet(url).reply(400); 
        const { status} = await axios.get(url) // here is error line
    })

})
```

My example mock data :

```
fetchUsersMockData = {
    pageIndex: 0,
    pageSize: 3,
    totalCount: 8,
    totalPages: 1,
    items: [
        {
            id: uuidv4(),
            username: "adminuser@test.com.tr",
            name: "Scot",
            surname: "Lawson",
            email: "adminuser@test.com.tr",
            phoneNumber: "03212342345",
            isActive: true,
            isLocked: false,
            timeZone: "Europe/Istanbul"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: try wrapping the error case in try/catch

Comment: Thank you.  Your answer was solved my problem.

Comment: Glad I could help, Please accept the answer so that it will be helpful for others too. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your error test scenario in `try...catch` block

Solution:

```
try {
  it("get has error", async () => {
        mock.onGet(url).reply(400); 
        const { status} = await axios.get(url) // here is error line
    })
}catch(e){
   code///
}
```

[More on Error Handling](https://javascript.info/async-await#error-handling)